# What's the method to de-serialize tfrecords in apache_beam

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-cloud-dataflow

I did found io functions in apache_beam specially for tfrecords, this works:

```
from apache_beam.io.tfrecordio import ReadFromTFRecord
class VerifyOutput(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, pcollection):
        try:
            pcollection = pcollection.element
        except AttributeError:
            pass
        logging.info(pcollection.subject_id)


(pipeline |  ReadFromTFRecord(opt.input_path, compression_type='auto', validate=True) 
          | beam.ParDo(VerifyOutput()) )
```

This will print out the bytestringa of the tfrecord. How to parse this inside a beam pipeline? Such to get the individual elements back?

I did find the tensorflow idiom for reading tfrecords [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/reading_data#Reading_from_files), but that didn't work for me, I suppose because beam is not "thread-safe" (hangs forever).

Also, is it possible (for debugging/learning/testing) to run ReadFromTFRecord without actually running a pipeline? In for example a jupyter notebook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the *coder* to decode the features back.
Something like this should do the job:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_transform as tft
from apache_beam.io.tfrecordio import ReadFromTFRecord
from tensorflow_transform.beam import impl as beam_impl
from tensorflow_transform.beam import tft_beam_io 
from tensorflow_transform.tf_metadata import dataset_metadata
from tensorflow_transform.tf_metadata import dataset_schema

...

# for each feature, adapt accordingly:
column_schemas['FEATURE_NAME']= dataset_schema.ColumnSchema(tf.int64, [], dataset_schema.FixedColumnRepresentation())

raw_data_metadata = dataset_metadata.DatasetMetadata(dataset_schema.Schema(column_schemas))
data_coder = tft.coders.ExampleProtoCoder(raw_data_metadata.schema)

_ = (pipeline | ReadFromTFRecord(opt.input_path, coder=data_coder, compression_type='auto', validate=True) 
              | beam.ParDo(VerifyOutput()) )
```

See also [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/transform/blob/master/examples/sentiment_example.py) for a more elaborate example.

However, consider that there are also (newer) alternatives to deal with TF record files and datasets (e.g. see [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/tf_records#reading_a_tfrecord_file_2) and [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/transform/get_started)).

Comment: Tnx for the answer, hope it helps someone! I've moved on with life and away from TF in the meantime ;-) but who knows, maybe I'll need it again sometime.